# database size would exceed your licensed limit of 4096 MB per database

Tags: sql-server, database

We are using sharepoint server 2007 and if i create any files and folders the sharepoint site is throwing some error "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E14"

and i checked event viewer.here also some error showing "

1. CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 4096 MB per database
2. Database full error on SQL Server instance 'mps\OfficeServers' in database 'WSS_Content'. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
   Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.EventCache'.'EventCache_Id' in database 'WSS_Content' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.
   i have backup some database and deleted unwanted database.now the database size is 2GB only (D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data).

[social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/9b3259cc-2bf6-4127-bd57-df3b866f6d8f](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/9b3259cc-2bf6-4127-bd57-df3b866f6d8f)

i have shrink the database also using below the URL

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190757.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190757.aspx)

But the 4GB error is again and again coming.

How to resolve this?Thanks in advance,Velmurugan

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you are using SQL Server Express, which has a 4G size limit. You'll need to upgrade you copy of SQL Server.

```
http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/sqlserver-tutorial-158.aspx
```

Comment: Actually just upgrade to SQL Server Express 2008 R2 - the limit was raised to 10gb there.

Comment: Express could indeed be tough to use with Sharepoint because it embeds the documents in the database and grows quite big with many documents.

Answer (score 1):

If that is not an option (upgrading sql) then you can create  a new content DB.. migrate some sites into the new DB to free up space in the old Content DB... Set the old content DB to "no new sites" and then you'll start filling up the new content db.